# Java 8 Stream iterate for merging Map<String,List<Object>>

Tags: java

I have a service to get employees list. I might need to call the service multiple times based on the number of results. The result from the service will be in the descending order and I need to fetch employees until some ids( lastEmpId ).

I do paging as below.

```
    Map<String, List<RetiredEmployee>> empsMap = new HashMap<>();
    int lastEmpId = 100;
    int empId = 10000;
    int offset = 0;
    int pageSize = 100;

    while ((pageSize > 0) && emp.getEmpId > lastEmpId) {

       final List<Employee> employeesList = empClient.getEmployees(pageSize, offset);

        // Merging each page with the global empsMap ...
        employeesList.stream()
        .map(RetiredEmployee::new)
        .filter(e -> e.getEmpJoinTime().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> 
         e.getEmployee().getName()))
         .entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> empsMap.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> {
            Set<RetiredEmployee> set = new TreeSet<>(v1);
            set.addAll(v2);
            return new ArrayList<>(set);
        }));;

        lastEmpId = employeesList.get(employeesList.size() - 1);
        pageSize = employeesList.size();
    }
```

Is there any better way to do the above thing using Stream.iterate without the while loop logic.

Thanks

Comment: You're better off just writing a helper method that handles the pagination logic separately from the stream processing.

Comment: `HashMap.merge()` is unsafe to call from a parallel stream.

Comment: Updated with normal stream. Thanks,

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to use parallel streams without careful consideration and testing. I don't expect you would benefit much from parallelization in this case.

Comment: Unless you're using Java 9, I don't think you'll be able to convert your while loop to a stream.

Comment: Any example in Java 9 for the same?

Comment: when you are mapping to RetiredEmployee::new are you not just ending up with a stream of initialized RetiredEmployees, losing everything?

Comment: You might be able to use `Stream.takeWhile()` to cut off the stream when you hit the end.

Comment: Nope, that is just for the paginated result.

Comment: @user1578872 really ahh you constructor for RetiredEmployee takes an employee? my bad.

Comment: This is for some other reason which i am adding here.